# Pycharm output is diverse when I paste the text in rows

Tags: python

The problem comes (in Pycharm) when:

Example1-OK:

How is your day?

And I answer: My day is going well.

(The code count spaces, commas and dots)

Than I push return and is ok: Your sentence has 5 signs.

Example2-WRONG:

How is your day?

And I answer (*with a copy paste sentence!): My day
is going well.

Output is *automated: My day
is going well.Your sentence has 1 sign.

So, it runs automatically, it counts just the first line and output my answer with attached program answer.

Maybe is the problem when you copy the multilines sentence and attach it in the answer, because you cant make another line in answer with return key.

Comment: Use this 'r\n' put this at the end of sentence

Comment: `input` doesn't support multiline input. You'd get the same behaviour in IDLE. To cite the documentation of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input): "The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that."